# SQLinstance problems

Tags: database-connection, shutdown, sql-server-2019, disconnect

SQL- I cannot connect to my instance after I shutdown my instance.
How do I connect to my instance?

Comment: please specify DB you use. Is it MS SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL or something different?

Comment: SQL server 2019

Comment: Is your SQL Service running? If the start up mode is not automatic then you should start it manually.

Comment: How does it? ///